# Consistency when it comes to using verbs

Tags: tense, verbs

Should I be consistent when using verb tenses? Once I use simple past, do I need to stick to it through out my conversation? Please see my examples below, as I think they would better explain what I'm trying to ask.

> "Mom **asked** me to go grocery shopping, but I **was wondering** if you **could** go instead. Here **is** the list of items she **wants**."
>
> "Mom **asked** me to go grocery shopping, but I **was wondering** if you **could** go instead. Here **is** the list of items she **wanted**."

I'm not sure if I should keep my tenses consistent and use "wanted". It seems like Mom still wants the items on the list, so I'm not sure if I should go with "wants".

Answer (score 3):

Grammatically, *the list of items she wants* and *the list of items she wanted* are both correct. What changes is the meaning.

I would use the past tense in the following case.

> Mom asked me to go grocery shopping, but I was wondering if you could go instead. Here is the list of items she **wanted**. Ask her if she wants something else.

The past tense in this case would mean the list is not updated; you are not sure she wants something more, or changed her mind about something she asked you to buy. It could be she asked you to go to the grocery store one hour before you could effectively go, and now that you are asking to somebody else to go to the grocery store you are not sure the list is updated.

The present tense would imply the list is updated.

In *here **is** the list* you use the present tense; you don't say *here **was** the list*.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the tense that conveys the meaning you intend. In other words, using consistent tenses is not the same as using the same tense throughout.

You discern correctly that since Mom still wants the items on the list it is preferred to use *she wants*.

You would only use *she wanted* if, for example, you think enough time has passed since she asked you to go, that she may have changed her mind about some of the items.